# Accepting donations in an app developed for a non-profit

Tags: ios, applepay

I've developed an app for a non-profit which is published by me, not the non-profit. It has gained traction and now we'd like to implement donations in-app via Apple Pay. I've read the Apple Pay documentation and I've verified that they're an approved non-profit, my concern is over generating a merchant ID.

Will Apple allow me to have a merchant ID for myself, but ultimately have Apple Pay connected to an account that the non-profit owns (via Stripe/Braintree/etc.)? Or for this to work does the non-profit need to have a developer account with the app published by them?

Comment: Hi @Ryan, what approach worked for you? have you able to provide native Apple Pay option from your app?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Without a clear path we opted to have a link in the app that opens a web page in Safari that allows a user to donate via PayPal. So it's possible it's doable, but would likely require a conversation with an Apple representative.